# Joining tables with Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I `INNER JOIN` a table that contains 2 foreign keys as its primary keys?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (table1ID CHAR(4));
CREATE TABLE MEM_INSTR (table2ID CHAR(4));
CREATE TABLE table3 (table1ID CHAR(4), table2ID CHAR(4));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If people look at you answer and all it is code, chances are they'll move away. I recommend that you revise your question with also your question in the post, not just the title.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to just join everything together as keys suggest...

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table3 on table3.table1ID = table1.table1ID
INNER JOIN MEM_INSTR on MEM_INSTR.table2ID = table3.table2ID
```

But let's say that you have this scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    Table1ID NUMBER, 
    Generation NUMBER, 
    ... 
);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    Table2ID NUMBER, 
    Table1ID NUMBER, 
    Table1Generation NUMBER, 
    ...
);
```

Let's say for argument's sake that Table1 can have multiple records with the same Table1ID, and Generation is used as a secondary key.  And you need to join a Table2 record to the *correct single* Table1 record.  You can expand the `ON` clause the same way you would expand a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.table1id = t1.table1id 
    AND t2.table1generation = t1.generation
```

Answer (score 0):

You join it like you usually do, nothing really special about that. So you go something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.table1ID = table1.table1ID
INNER JOIN MEM_INSTR ON MEM_INSTR.table2ID = table3.table2ID
```

Comment: This looks an awful lot like @aaaantoine's answer