# inner join with 2 primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

ending with id meaning is the primary key but what do i do when table 4 uses 2 primary keys?
Display content2, content3, and content1 in 1 select statement

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(table1ID   CHAR(4),
 content1   VARCHAR,

CREATE TABLE table2
(table2ID   CHAR(4),
 content2   VARCHAR,

CREATE TABLE tablet3
(table3ID   CHAR(4),
 content3   VARCHAR,
 table2ID    CHAR(4),

CREATE TABLE tablet4
(table1ID   CHAR(4),
 table3ID   CHAR(4),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining tables with Foreign Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875303/joining-tables-with-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
 SELECT content1
       ,content2
       ,content3
  FROM           table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.table1ID = t4.table1ID
      INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t4.table3ID = t3.table3ID
      INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.table2ID = t2.table2ID
```

Comment: btw, I changed tablet3 to table3 and same for 4. I assumed was the pattern.